# Does background-size: cover stretch a background image?

Tags: html, css, background-image

Does `background-size: cover;` in CSS stretch a background image?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see? Better yet, [read about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It can stretch or constriction depending on image & background size.**
 [image]It will crops the extra portion which does not matched to div size.
Suppose you have a div with `400*250`, and the background image is `400*350`. If you use `background-size: cover`, then to cover all background it need to **crop 100px** height extra.

- or, if you use 200*150 background image, then to cover all the
  background it is needed to extend the image minimum 400*300
  (200:150=2:1.5, multiply by 2 will 400*300, mind that if height
  increases, width also will be increased proportionally)
- if we make the image 200*150 to 333.33*250, width will be not covered. (though 
  height is ok)
- if background image size u used is 800*500 or 200*125 or same proportion to it, no portion of image will be cut down, will see
  whole image
- For, 8000*500 size image, it will compressed to cover 400*250 sized background, no portion will cut down but image will be compressed to fit.

*Finally, background-size cover property will large or compress the image until all background will be covered, it don't care how waste the image will be.*

Answer (score -1):

Yes it does. Consider using contain if this is not what you're looking for. Here is a simple guide:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: I have an application with a re-sizable window and I want the background iamge to scale to fill up the background without stretching. Would contain do this for me?

Comment: *Yes it does* --> no it deosn't not.

Comment: @TemaniAfif It does.

Comment: @MARSHMALLOW *Scales the image as large as possible without stretching the image. If the proportions of the image differ from the element, it is cropped either vertically or horizontally so that no empty space remains.* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size (note the *without stretching*)

Comment: @MARSHMALLOW and from the Spec(https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#the-background-size) : *Scale the image, while preserving its intrinsic aspect ratio (if any), to the smallest size such that both its width and its height can completely cover the background positioning area.*  (note the preseving its ratio == no stretching)

Comment: if background size is 600*400, then the ratio is 3:2, so you must use a background image with this ratio to show all the image to entire background, like 300*200, 600*400, 900*600